# how to convert microsoft 2016 sql ddl load scripts to postgres sql

Tags: postgresql, database-migration

I would like to translate Microsoft SQL Server DDL and table load sql commands to the Postgres equivalent.

There are a number of tools to convert one database to another in the link below but are there parsers for ddl/sql script conversion?

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#Microsoft_SQL_Server

Comment: If I understand you want to adapt DDL written in C# and code written in T-SQL to PostgreSQL?

Comment: it is all t-sql

Comment: Maybe this: http://www.sqlines.com/sql-server-to-postgresql-tool but I haven't tried it

Comment: thanks the link sqlines.com/sql-server-to-postgresql-tool  sort of works but some datatypes like nvarchar do not get converted properly for some reason

Comment: Is the SQL Server database still running? Then maybe using [pgLoader](https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/mssql.html) might be an easier option

Comment: no - I just want to convert the scripts themselves

Comment: @user11020868: you will never get a full automated 100% identical conversion. You have to expect a substantial amount of manual work.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name is right, you can use whatever tool that can maybe translate 80% of the code but then you have to review that 20% with a human brain. Try to ask this question on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: cross posting on dba.stackexchange https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/269119/convert-microsoft-server-sql-to-postgres-sql